# Why git core is deleted everyday on Azure webapp?

Tags: github, azure-web-app-service, apt-get, linux-containers, azure-webapps

I've installed git-core on Azure webapp and during the next day the git commands won't work. Every day I need to reinstall the git-core and the other components.

I need to put this script everyday :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y git-core
apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

Are there parameters to set in the azure portal interface or a script to insert in appservice files content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any parameters from the portal that will set dependencies of your container (it's temporary). Rather, what you should do is construct your container with your dependencies installed on it. Create your own dockerfile with your apt-get install commands and publish to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/appsvc/) for use from your web app.

Hope this helps.